# Use two tables in one php page (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to retrieve all the data onto one page... I've got this working fine when it's retrieving from one table like so:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM moduleDetails")
```

I've tried doing

```
("SELECT * FROM moduleDetails, qResponses")
```

but that doesn't work and is the only thing I can see working.

I've heard about using identifiers? But I'm not quite sure how to use those...

I am new to PHP, any tips/examples would be great.

Comment: You need to specify how to join those two tables. What column links them together?

Comment: I've got a userno, like a unique number for each participant of the questionniare - how would i use that?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT md.*, qr.*
FROM moduleDetails md
LEFT JOIN qResponses qr
ON qr.joinColumn = md.joinColumn
```

Whatever column you used to link them together, use as the joinColumn.

Comment: YES you can't just select all from 2 tables without joining them.

Comment: so like this?  $data = mysql_query(
 SELECT md.*, qr.*
 FROM moduleDetails md
 LEFT JOIN qResponses qr
 ON qr.userno = md.userno)

Comment: PHP interpret everything that is not in quotes as being `constants` or `functions`. The query should be set as a `variable`. To do so, you should contain it inside quotes

Comment: `$data = mysql_query('SELECT md.*, qr.* FROM moduleDetails md LEFT JOIN qResponses qr ON qr.userno = md.userno');` **DON'T EVER FORGET THE SEMICOLON WHEN YOU END A LINE**

Comment: IFF the tables are not actually linked in any way, you could use a `UNION` statement, which simply selects rows from first table, and then the next.  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp